# How to modify a string inside a JSON object and convert it into another JSON object and thus add a key value with Python?

Tags: python, json, formatting

I would like to find a way to convert a string inside my JSON object into another JSON object (nested)  with the use of Python and thus add a key to the values inside my string that are separated by the use of a "**;**".

**My current JSON object:**

```
   {
    "reference": "#############",
    "messageContext": "",
    "from": {
        "number": "+#############",
        "name": ""
    },
    "to": {
        "number": "#############"
    },
    "message": {
        "text": "12302;8;6245;d517666e-41ca-459a-9b35-c49386df537b;2;2;50.8447;-4.3614;2021-04-28T22:24:12.204Z;rec123;PRD",
        "media": {
            "mediaUri": "",
            "contentType": "",
            "title": ""
        },
        "custom": {}
    },
    "groupings": [
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "time": "2021-05-02 14:03:22",
    "timeUtc": "2021-05-02T12:03:22",
    "channel": "Sms"
   }
```

The format I would try to have is something like this, where I would change the text to an object while adding key values.

**Result, which I try to obtain** (Inside of ***text:" "***):

```
   {
   "reference": ""#############",",
   "messageContext": "",
   "from": {
       "number": "+"#############",",
       "name": ""
   },
   "to": {
       "number": ""#############","
   },
   "message": {
       "text": {
           "APSI": "12302",
           "idVhl": 8,
           "idDrv": 6245,
           "GUID": "d517666e-41ca-459a-9b35-c49386df537b",
           "idLne": 2,
           "idSvc": 2,
           "Lat": 50.8447,
           "Lon": -4.3614,
           "Timestamp": "2021-04-28T22:24:12.204Z",
           "Rec": "rec123",
           "Env": "PRD"
       },
       "media": {
           "mediaUri": "",
           "contentType": "",
           "title": ""
       },
       "custom": {}
   },
   "groupings": [
       "",
       "",
       ""
   ],
   "time": "2021-05-02 14:03:22",
   "timeUtc": "2021-05-02T12:03:22",
   "channel": "Sms"
}
```

Comment: Could you also post what you have tried and the problems you encountered?

Comment: Hello @CristiFati I have tried a few things, I read something about using json.loads to try to format it into an object and try to retrieve the "text" value first, but it keeps telling me "Result: Failure
Exception: keyError: 'text'""

Comment: You should add that into the question. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Given your JSON object as `input` this function will return your expected output.

```py
def transform(input):
    text = input['message']['text']
    text_list = text.split(';')
    text_dict = {
        'APSI': text_list[0],
        'idVhl': int(text_list[1]),
        'idDrv': int(text_list[2]),
        'GUID': text_list[3],
        'idLne': int(text_list[4]),
        'idSvc': int(text_list[5]),
        'Lat': float(text_list[6]),
        'Lon': float(text_list[7]),
        'Timestamp': text_list[8],
        'Rec': text_list[9],
        'Env': text_list[10]
    }
    input['message']['text'] = text_dict
    return input
```

This is done by splitting your `text` on the `;` character which returns a list of all the values you want. You can then parse the list into a dictionary and then assign that dictionary to your original `text` value.